# Dropdown always align center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to make dropdown always align center, according to the parent tag. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The example is given below:

[image]

`Fiddle Link:` http://jsfiddle.net/abidkhanweb/ojxpt4m2/

Comment: can you provide the markup?

Comment: Without code is difficult, but control the specificity of your css rules.

Comment: I assume your parent/child nodes have various width and you would like to  apply one styling for all of them?

Comment: I think this should possibly with jquery or javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
#menu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD; 
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 18pt;
    line-height: 18pt;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    font-size:14px;
    position:absolute;  
}

#menu > li{
    background-color: #003399;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    margin-top:-1px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}

#menu li:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}



#menu li .wrapper .submenu {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 50%;
    width:100%;
}

#menu li .wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 19pt;
    right: 50%; /*this will center the div*/
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#menu li:hover .wrapper .submenu {
    display: block;
}

.submenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 1.5%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.submenu li a {
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    background-color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
}


#menu ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  list-style-image:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
#menu li.topmenu {
  float:left;
}


.topmenu a {
  float:left;
  width:110px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#C37000;
  padding:1px 5px;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin:0;  
}

.topmenu ul{
 display:none;
}


.submenu a{
  padding:1px 5px;
  border:1px solid #C37000;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  color:#C37000;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:#7F4800;
  margin:0;
  width:100%;  
}

.submenu a:hover {
  color:#4C4C4C;
  background-color:#ffddbb !important;
}
.topmenu:hover ul {
  display:block;  
  z-index:500;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#">Policies</a>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul >
                <li class="submenu"><a>Field 1</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a>Field 2</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a>Field 3</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a>Field 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good..! but when i add some text on a tag is gone wrong

Comment: when i add some text on a tag. the text is overflow form ul

Comment: you can simply remove `white-space: nowrap;` from `#menu li .wrapper`  css

Comment: but i need flexible when i add more content then container should be big

Comment: I added only [width:100%] on [.submenu and submenu a] tag...Thank you @Amani

Comment: And also there are padding issue i will manage, this is helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have applied `position: absolute` to the dropdown, for you to position it to the left, set the `left` property to the value of your padding for the policies container like so:

```css
nav {
    background: orange;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: green;
}

nav > ul ul {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Policies</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Policy 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Policy 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Policy 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Policy 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: May not work due to variable width of parent node & child items.

Comment: @adrian.krzysztofek that's true, but the poster hasn't provided any reference code. This is a barebones example to illustrate how he could achieve this.

Comment: Sure thing. Also, it is better to have this solution than none at all.